# Angularjs - how much data is too much for client-side?

Tags: angularjs

I don't know if this question is too simplistic - but are there any sort of best practices or guidelines when it comes to deciding how much data is too much for client side processing (sorting/filtering) with AngularJS.

I am wondering if it make sense to build some sort of trigger into my code - perhaps when the data set reaches a certain size do all manipulation on the server side, if its below that size do it on client side. Is that overkill? Am I over thinking this?

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I do not think this is a question for stack overflow. We're here to help you with specific coding problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only every send the amount of data to the client that it needs, that includes aggregate data if the client only needs aggregate data.

The most to send is also however much the client need to function.

Optimise for performance AFTER you have a working client, not before.

This is true for any client, not just Angular.